# asp.net web project path - parser error - The virtual path maps to another application, which is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, path, virtual

I have a web site project which include a folder named - `/pix`. Under the pix folder I have an aspx page - `BPDList.aspx`. This page is related to a master page. This is the first line on the page -

```
<%@ Page Title="K online" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="../MasterPage.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BPDPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="BPDPage" %>
```

The file `MasterPage.master` exist in the root of my web project (one level above the folder pix).
I receive the following error :

`"Parser Error Message: The virtual path '/MasterPage.master' maps to another application, which is not allowed."`

When changing the path to - `"~/MasterPage.master"` I receive this error:

`"Parser Error Message: The file '/pix/MasterPage.master' does not exist."`

How can I reffer to a file in another directory?
Why does the 'pix' folder defined as an application?